# MySQL concat with not exits condition

Tags: mysql

this works

```
SELECT USERID, FNAME, LNAME FROM USERS WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(?, ' ', '%'), '%', '%')"
```

but i want to addon this

```
TBL USERS 

USERID   FNAME    LNAME    EMAIL 
1        JONE      DEO     tes@doe.com
2        JANE      DEO     tes1@deo.com
3        Jow       DEO     tdb@deo.com


TBL MSG 

MSGID    RECEIVED    READ 
1        YES         YES 
2        NO          NO 
3        NO          NO
```

THIS IS MY TRY

```
SELECT USERID, FNAME, LNAME FROM USERS WHERE CONCAT(FNAME, ', ', LNAME, ', ', EMAIL) LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE(?, ' ', '%'), '%', '%' WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM MSG WHERE 
RECEIVED = 'YES' AND  READ = 'YES' ))"
```

so i want to select only users which not exits in RECEIVED(YES) AND READ (YES)

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables ? How do you `join` them ?

Comment: am not joining them am just selecting from tbl users

Comment: How would anyone come to know of which msg belong to which user ?